# Angular test error even though property exists in component

Tags: javascript, angular

I get the following error when running `ng test`:

```
Can't bind to 'foobar' since it isn't a known property of 'app-my-item'.

1. If 'app-my-item' is an Angular component and it has 'foobar' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-my-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Renderer, EventEmitter, Output, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-item',
  templateUrl: './app-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-item.component.scss'],
})

export class MyItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() video;
  @Input() foobar = <string> '';
  buttonClass = 'green';

  // Code....

  ngOnChanges({ foobar: { currentValue } }: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (currentValue) {
      this.buttonClass = (
        currentValue === this.video.key ? 'blue' : 'green'
      );
    }
  }

  // Code....

}
```

**View:**

```
  <app-my-item
      //Code ....
      [foobar]="foobar"
      //Code ....
  >
  </app-my-item>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error because `foobar` is in fact defined in the component as an input. How to fix this error?

Comment: Is it possible that the default assignment there to the empty string is making it lose track?

Comment: @MotKohn just changed `@Input() foobar = <string> '';` to `@Input() foobar;`and still same error :(

Comment: Can you add your module file please?

Comment: Which component are you testing? `app-item` or some other component?